# Entity Framework - parent child relationship with non-matching columns

Tags: entity-framework

Is it possible to have a parent/child relationship with two entities with composite keys where the column names don't match?

eg. 
Table A's composite key fields are (CustNmbr, SiteId) 
Table B's composite key fields are (Account, SiteNumber)

I've tried all kinds of mappings and can't seem to make it work. Based on what's I've read, you should be able to map this out in the model. I've tried and failed rather miserably:

```
  public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer_Contract_Data> Contracts { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Configure the primary Key for the OfficeAssignment 
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.CustNmbr, t.SiteId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.Contracts)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(t => new { t.CustNmbr, t.SiteId });
    } 


    // function that retursn all orders
    private IQueryable<Customer> getCustomers()
    {
        // return the data
        return Customers;
    }

    public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        return getCustomers().ToList();
    }

    // function that retursn all orders
    public Customer GetCustomer(Int32 siteId, string custNbr)
    {
        // return the data
        return getCustomers().Include(m=>m.Contracts).FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustNmbr == custNbr && x.SiteId == siteId); ;
    }

    // dispose
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Here are the class structures

```
[Table("CustomerData")]
public class Customer
{
    [Key, Column(Order=2)]
    public string CustNmbr { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public Int32 SiteId { get; set; }

    public string GPCompany { get; set; }
    public string CustName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string CCode { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Phone1 { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUploadedFromLive { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Customer_Contract_Data> Contracts { get; set; }

    public Customer() { }

}

[Table("Customer_Contract_Data")]
public class Customer_Contract_Data
{
    [Key]
    public string Contractnumber { get; set; }

    public Int32 SiteNumber { get; set; }
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public string Contracttype { get; set; }
    public string Contracttypedescription { get; set; }
    public string Servicetype { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public DateTime Contractstartdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Contractenddate { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure,
see code below (I simplified your entities)  :

mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasKey(t => new { t.CustomerNumber, t.SiteId }) //composite key
    .HasMany(t => t.Contracts)
    .WithRequired(t => t.Customer);

modelBuilder.Entity<ContractData>() // child entity
    .HasKey(c => new { c.ContractNumber, c.Account }) // composite key
    .HasRequired(c => c.Customer) // parent relation
    .WithMany()
    .Map(c => c.MapKey("column1", "column2")); //mapping to different column names
```

entities:

```
public class ContractData
{
    public virtual string ContractNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string Account { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Contracts = new List<ContractData>();
    }

    public virtual string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual int SiteId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ContractData> Contracts { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

underlying DB:

```
Customer          1 <---> n   ContractData
-----------------             -----------------
CustomerNumber PK             column1        FK
SiteId         PK             column2        FK
Name                          ContractNumber PK
                              Account        PK
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I was wandering around a bit on this one. This looks good. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome. Try it out and let me know if it's all right.